# How to change chainrings on this Tiagra crankset?

Tags: shimano, crankset, chainring, tiagra

I want to switch to 46/30 but don't know how to begin. The crankset is Shimano Tiagra FC-4700, 50x34T, 170mm

[image: left side view of the crankset]
[image: right side view of the crankset]

Comment: The smallest chainrings you can get for your 110mm BCD crankset are 34 or 33 teeth.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The crankset (110 BCD - [Bolt Circle Diameter](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index-a-list-of-bike-part-names-and-cycling-concepts/55802#55802)) is unlikely to accept a 30T chainring. It definitely isn't supported by Shimano. You need a new crank.

Look at subcompact cranksets like, e.g., FSA Tempo Adventure (10/11 speed). Note that this specific one also uses a different bottom bracket.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know that there's a BCD and what it was. But after your answer I googled it and found this article: https://corbah.com/blogs/bike-talk/should-i-get-a-110bcd-crankset-or-130bcd-crankset . Maybe someone else will find it useful: contains a table for different BCDs.

Answer (score 2):

Shimano offers the FC-RX600-10 in their gravel bike line which comes with 46/30 chainrings.  The chainline is a little outboard of the road chainline (by 3.5 mm).  You may be able to adjust the stops on your front derailleur to fit or you may need a new gravel one.  I also don't know if it fits your bottom bracket.